# Angular js objects of objects displaying last content

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, javascript-objects

I have my model data like this:

```
     {
  "0": [
    {
      "question": "How often is real property re-assessed (or revalued)?",
      "id": 1,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often second?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often third?",
      "id": 2,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "key": "Survey Meta Data"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "question": "When are New Assessment Notices sent out?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "Assessment"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I want to display in my html the **key first** and **then all my  questions**

***Note:*** if I reverse my data then problem is the key will be display first but the questions order also get inverted I dont want to reverse my question , in short what I wan t is to display the key first and then the format of data must remain same ***i.e its something like pushing key to the top index***
i.e something like this:

```
     {
  "0": [
    {
      "key": "Survey Meta Data"
    },
    {
      "question": "How often is real property re-assessed (or revalued)?",
      "id": 1,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often second?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often third?",
      "id": 2,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "key": "Assessment"
    },
    {
      "question": "When are New Assessment Notices sent out?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 1
    }

  ]
}
```

**or**

```
     {
  "0": [
    {
      "question": "How often is real property re-assessed (or revalued)?",
      "id": 1,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often second?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "question": "How often third?",
      "id": 2,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 0
    },

      "key": "Survey Meta Data"

  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "question": "When are New Assessment Notices sent out?",
      "id": 3,
      "section": "Assessment",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "check": true,
      "index": 1
    },

      "key": "Assessment" //treat it as object value not object of object

  ]
}
```

currently my html with ng-repeat is not working good it basically iterates the question first then the key is displayed but I want questions first then the key:

```
    <div ng-repeat="data in viewQuestions">
<div class="panel panel-default"  ng-repeat="value in data">
     {{value.key}}

   label>{{value.question}} </label>

     </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Why is `data` an object with stringified numbers for keys instead of just an array?

Comment: data  is an object of object and keys are in stringified from the backend for now I just hard coded to explain my problem

Comment: Please read [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)

Answer (score 0):

The better options would be to get data from your api properly formatted of course, but if for some reason you cannot, you can do the following trick after getting data:

```
<html ng-app="QuestionsApp">
<body ng-controller="QuestionsController">
  <div ng-repeat="data in viewQuestions">
    <div class="panel panel-default"  ng-repeat="value in data | orderBy : 'showIndex'">
      <strong ng-if="value.key">{{value.key}}</strong>
      <label ng-if="value.question">{{value.question}}</label>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var QuestionsApp = angular.module('QuestionsApp', []);

  QuestionsApp.controller('QuestionsController', function QuestionsController($scope) {
    var keyIndex = -1;
    var apiResponse = {
      "0": [
        {
          "question": "How often is real property re-assessed (or revalued)?",
          "id": 1,
          "section": "Assessment",
          "sectionId": 2,
          "check": true,
          "index": 0
        },
        {
          "question": "How often second?",
          "id": 3,
          "section": "Assessment",
          "sectionId": 2,
          "check": true,
          "index": 0
        },
        {
          "question": "How often third?",
          "id": 2,
          "section": "Assessment",
          "sectionId": 2,
          "check": true,
          "index": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "Survey Meta Data"
        }
      ],
      "1": [
        {
          "question": "When are New Assessment Notices sent out?",
          "id": 3,
          "section": "Assessment",
          "sectionId": 2,
          "check": true,
          "index": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Assessment"
        }
      ]
    }

    angular.forEach(apiResponse, function (questions) {
      angular.forEach(questions, function (question, index) {
        if (question.key) question.showIndex = keyIndex;
        else question.showIndex = index;
      });
    });

    $scope.viewQuestions = apiResponse;
  });
</script>
</html>
```

The trick is to add the `showIndex` field and `value in data | orderBy : 'showIndex'`